# Performance hit when splitting in multiple assembly's

Tags: performance, asp.net-core, dll, .net-assembly

Hello i currently have a `ASP NET Core application`that is written as a big `assembly` that contains everything , all logic in my solution and i was wondering what will be the performance hit if split it up in multiple assemblies.

Will there be a huge hit in performance since it will load parts from it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There will be some minor, probably not even noticeable, performance hit at startup. After that [don't even worry about it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16322754/64348). .NET in all its incarnations has been optimized for years.

Most [advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18859582/single-dll-v-multiple-dlls) talks about splitting assemblies based on functionality. This has been my personal experience. If you're splitting (or not) for performance reasons rather than architectural reasons, you most likely have a bigger issue.

If there is no specific driver to split your assembly such as reuse or performance, don't do it. Laziness is useful in a project. If you start splitting with no real reason you increase accidental complexity by, for example, introducing potential [versioning issues](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1215043/64348) and having extra artifacts to deploy/maintain.